# How is it possible to open restricted site on client browser using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy

I have deployed an `asp.net` website on server, whenever user logs in my site it redirect to user another website `https://10.10.10.9/`, only web hosting server has access to this site when I open website on hosting server it redirect user to `https://10.10.10.9/` but when I open website on client machine it is not redirecting to above mentioned IP address. How can I achieve this in `asp.net`?

Comment: a question hard to understand for me. you should examplize your sites like siteA and siteB. you should detailize server access like browsing over vps or requesting by code. you should mention your code clearly like how it does redirect(even how it logs user). i see only one ip address in the question and i only understand that that is your site

Comment: I have deployed a site on server 10.10.1.63,now whenever user request to my site it redirects to another site with IP 10.10.10.9. IP 10.10.10.9 only accessible on server 10.10.1.63.When i open site on server 10.10.1.63 my site successfully redirect to 10.10.10.9 but when i open site on client machine browser my site is not redirecting to 10.10.10.9

Comment: how do you make .9 only accesible on server .63 and how do you redirect(simple response.redirect("ip");?) i am not familiar with this scenerio, i may advise you to focus on accessibility. for example if you restrict access by ip, the incoming ip is client s ip when you browse on client and it s server s ip when you browse over server

Comment: Our network administrator make .9 only accessible on .63 now scenario is we don't want to give access of .9 to every client,we want to give access of .9 only 63 and client can access .63 where our website is deployed.